# Producing a list in Racket, with a list of Daytime Structure

Tags: list, racket

I want to write a function that

> 1- consumes a natural number(interval)
>
> 2- produces a schedule which is a list of the daytime structure as
>   shown below.

The rule is that for every list produced, the schedule starts at (6am), increases by the given interval, and continues to add that interval until it ends at (6pm- which is the 18th hour) and doesn't go past that mark. 
Using the data definition of:

```
    (define-struct daytime (hours minutes))
    ;; A Daytime is a (make-daytime Nat Nat)
    ;; requires the number that represents hours to be 6<= hours <= 18
    ;; and requires the number that represents minutes to be < 60
```

**The problem I am having** is how do I create lists with the daytime structure? I created a list but it uses "list" instead of make-day.
An example of this program should be:

```
    (schedule 90) gives 
    (list (make-daytime 6 0) (make-daytime 7 30) (make-daytime 9 0)
          (make-daytime 10 30) (make-daytime 12 0) (make-daytime 13 30)
          (make-daytime 15 0) (make-daytime 16 30) (make-daytime 18 0))
```

Comment: But you already created the list that works as you wanted! Try (define my-list (list (make-daytime 6 0)....) then you can try (daytime-hours (first (my-list))) which will give 6. If you want more visibility, add #:prefab to your define-struct and you'll see the details of the full list when you print it.

Comment: No that was an example to show you how i want my program to run. Can you please help me write this program out?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, define a function that'll return that list? Hmm, and the example you want will give you the intervals of n minutes.

There are many ways to write this, generally based on loops (recursive or not). If you want to use a for loop, you will need a sequence of values to iterate over. If you use recursion, you can increment the value until the end condition meets. You can increment a value within a for loop, but it uses mutation and is considered a poor approach in functional programming. Let me show you the way of two approaches, and leave some fine details to you :)

Also, I'll choose for/list for the loop operator, since it'll nicely return a list for us.

for loop: As I said, we need values to iterate over, so we can use a sequence function to create the values. Let's use (in-range) function for it:

```
(sequence->list (in-range 0 (* 12 60) 90))
```

will give you the minute increments:

```
'(0 90 180 270 360 450 540 630)
```

Perfect, we can work on this:

```
(define (schedule n)
  (for/list ([val (sequence->list (in-range 0 (* 12 60) n))])
    (let ([hour 0] ; <== calculate the hour part here
          [minute 0]) ; <== and minute here
      (make-daytime hour minute))))
```

Now, if you want to do the same recursively:

```
(define (schedule.v2 n)
  (define (schedule-aux result current-min)
    (cond
      [(>= current-min 720) result]
      [else
       (let ([hour 0] ; <== calculate the hour from current-min
             [minute 0] ; <== calculate the min from current-min
             [next-min (+ current-min n)])
         (schedule-aux
          (cons (make-daytime hour minute)
                result)
          next-min))]))
  (schedule-aux null 0))
```